# Area Chart in Altair with Negative Numbers: Fill 'below' the line, not 'above'

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have a set of data that is all negative values. I want to 'fill' the area under the curve, rather the above the curve to the 0 line (default behavior, as seen in the image).

Provided is a simplified version of the data and output.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': range(10),
    'y': [-2, -1, -3, -2, -4, -3, -4, -2, -3, -4],
})
alt.Chart(data).mark_area().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y')
```

[image: above code showing fill to 0]

In reality, the data set is time series of groundwater levels. There are thousands of data points for many different locations. As such, the max and min values in each graph will be different.

Is there a way to fill the reverse/inverse area to the default fill? in excel it looks something like this:
[image: example in excel]

note:

- 0 to remain at the 'top' of the graph'.
- number must remain negative
- min and max values are not known ahead of time

(edited for clarity.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example :

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': range(10),
    'y': [-2, -1, -3, -2, -4, -3, -4, -2, -3, -4],
})
alt.Chart(data).mark_area().encode(
    x='x',
    y= alt.Y('y', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, -4), nice=False)))
```

Comment: thanks! However, this code inverts the axis. I require 0 to be at the 'top' of the graph as per the excel example.